# Combining common code in functions as individual function in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on an application in C++, and a small part of that involves appending the date and time in array values, so I've created a couple of functions that get these values and make them look more user-friendly. There's a common chunk of code between the two functions, and I can't remember for the life of me how to stick it in it's own function and have it work as it does currently. The full code is below:

```
// GetDateAndTime.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

string getTime();
string getDate();

int main()
{
    string theTime = getTime();
    string theDate = getDate();

    cout << "It is " << theTime << " on " << theDate << endl;

    return 0;
}

string getTime()
{
    // define variables
    string strHour;
    string strMin;

    // get local time
    time_t now;
    struct tm nowLocal;
    now = time(NULL);
    nowLocal = *localtime(&now);

    int hour = nowLocal.tm_hour;
    int min = nowLocal.tm_min;

    // send hour value to string
    stringstream ssHour;
    ssHour << hour;
    if (hour >= 0 && hour <= 9)
    {
        strHour = "0" + ssHour.str();
    }
    else
    {
        strHour = ssHour.str();
    }

    // send min value to string
    stringstream ssMin;
    ssMin << min;
    if (min >= 0 && min <= 9)
    {
        strMin = "0" + ssMin.str();
    }
    else
    {
        strMin = ssMin.str();
    }

    string curTime = strHour + ":" + strMin;

    return curTime;
}

string getDate()
{
    // define variables
    string strDay;
    string strMonth;
    string strYear;

    // get local time
    time_t now;
    struct tm nowLocal;
    now = time(NULL);
    nowLocal = *localtime(&now);

    int day = nowLocal.tm_mday;
    int month = nowLocal.tm_mon + 1;
    int year = nowLocal.tm_year + 1900;

    // send day value to string
    stringstream ssDay;
    ssDay << day;
    if (day >= 1 && day <= 9)
    {
        strDay = "0" + ssDay.str();
    }
    else
    {
        strDay = ssDay.str();
    }

    // send month value to string
    stringstream ssMonth;
    ssMonth << month;
    if (month >= 1 && month <= 9)
    {
        strMonth = "0" + ssMonth.str();
    }
    else
    {
        strMonth = ssMonth.str();
    }

    // send year value to string
    stringstream ssYear;
    ssYear << year;
    strYear = ssYear.str();

    string curDate = strDay + "/" + strMonth + "/" + strYear;

    return curDate;
}
```

The code block in question is the one commented as "get local time". I'd appreciate any help at all! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function called `getLocalTime`. This function will do what these 4 lines contains. In both `getTime` and `getDate` you'll call it.

Comment: Great, thank you! I had an idiot moment, I ran the function before without setting a return and without declaring a variable in the child functions. It's working perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the include of stdafx.h because I couldn't compile with it, and it worked fine without it.

```
using namespace std;

string getTime();
string getDate();

string prepareValueForAddingToString(int dateThing) {
    string str;
    stringstream ssDateThing;
    ssDateThing *2 left arrows* dateThing;
    if (dateThing >= 1 && dateThing <= 9)
    {
        str = "0" + ssDateThing.str();
    }
    else {
        str = ssDateThing.str();
    }
    return str;
}


int main()
{
    string theTime = getTime();
    string theDate = getDate();

    cout << "It is " << theTime << " on " << theDate << endl;

    return 0;
}


string getTime()
{
    // define variables
    string strHour;
    string strMin;

    // get local time
    time_t now;
    struct tm nowLocal;
    now = time(NULL);
    nowLocal = *localtime(&now);

    int hour = nowLocal.tm_hour;
    int min = nowLocal.tm_min;

    // send hour value to string
    string curTime;
    curTime += prepareValueForAddingToString(hour);
    curTime += ":";
    curTime += prepareValueForAddingToString(min);

    return curTime;
}

string getDate()
{
    // define variables
    string strDay;
    string strMonth;
    string strYear;

    // get local time
    time_t now;
    struct tm nowLocal;
    now = time(NULL);
    nowLocal = *localtime(&now);

    int day = nowLocal.tm_mday;
    int month = nowLocal.tm_mon + 1;
    int year = nowLocal.tm_year + 1900;


    // send day value to string
    string curDate;
    curDate += prepareValueForAddingToString(day);
    curDate += "/";

    curDate += prepareValueForAddingToString(month);
    curDate += "/";

    curDate += prepareValueForAddingToString(year);

    return curDate;
}
```

An example output: It is 15:26 on 07/04/2017

Comment: The prepareValueForAddingString function has really helped reduce the amount of code I need, thank you so much!